# Unknown Build Error After Switching to .NET framework 4.7.2

Tags: .net, csproj, build-error, .net-4.7.2

Since switching a C# project from .NET framework 4.6.1 to 4.7.2 I get the following build error:

> Unknown build error, 'Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DependencyAttribute' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.'

I already checked my `.csproj` file and tried updating all my referenced assemblies but have no idea what could cause this.

Comment: You may want to try deleting all your bin and obj folders manually (or with a script). "Rebuild" and "Clean" don't always work as you might hope.

Comment: 1. Remove the binding redirects from the app.config file for the assemblies that are now part of the System.Runtime. 2. Remove the Nuget Package System.Runtime and then reinstall it.

Comment: 1. I removed bin and obj => no change
2. I checked app.conf and package.conf, I could not find any redirects.
3. When I go to "Manage NuGet Packages" I do not find a package System Runtime. Maybe I do not understand what you mean:

Comment: Upgrade the nuget packages to latest.

Comment: Thanks, already updated the NuGet Packages. Also did not change.

Comment: 1. Check all `App.config` files for redirects and delete them.
2. Execute `Update-Package -reinstall` to reinstall all NuGet packages in order to target net472